# Alternative for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, gui

I was wondering if there is an alternative for Visual Studio. My PC isn't the best, so Visual Studio takes a lot of time to start/load etc.

Mainly I would like to use C#

Is there any alternatives for Windows?

(Any price range)

Comment: What features do you need? What language(s) do you need it to support?

Comment: Mainly I would like to use C#

Comment: Honestly, if loading time is your concern, you should consider to spend some money into better hardware.

Comment: I agree, buy an SSD and have at least 8 GB RAM. VS 2010+ runs very well, I doubt that you will find a faster C# IDE. Mono/Xamarin studio is faster, but it doesn't have all of the features. If you don't need many features and value speed, you can try a plain text editor, like Notepad++ (with plugins for C# development), or Sublime Text, and use a compiler with them, although I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)
- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

It's worth noting that MonoDevelop is usually used for developing mono/C# which excludes WPF.

I've no experience regarding SharpDevelop but heard nothing bad about it.

Regarding launch time: In my opinion MonoDevelop is faster than VisualStudio, but only because I've 0 extensions in MonoDevelop.

You could probably take a look at how many extensions you currently have installed and remove some. Or shrink your projects. At least in my experience, a big project is worse than multiple small projects when it comes to loading times.